# Issue applying steering force to car controller

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am attempting to follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CdPYlj5uZeI) tutorial from Very Very Valet to script my own car controller (in the hopes that I can become more familiar with game physics), but am struggling to implement the steering force.

Currently I have the following code:

```cs
private void _steering()
{
    var tyreTransform = transform;
    Vector3 steeringDirection = tyreTransform.right;
    Vector3 tyreWorldVelocity = _carRigidbody.GetPointVelocity(tyreTransform.position);
    float steeringVelocity = Vector3.Dot(steeringDirection, tyreWorldVelocity);
    
    // 100% grip for now
    float desiredVelocityChange = -steeringVelocity * 1f;
    float desiredAccelerationChange = desiredVelocityChange / Time.fixedDeltaTime;
    var appliedForce = desiredAccelerationChange * _configuration.tyreMass * steeringDirection;
    
    _carRigidbody.AddForceAtPosition(appliedForce, tyreTransform.position);
}
```

which is called in the `FixedUpdate()` of each individual wheel node (guarded by a hit test to ensure the wheel is actually making contact with the ground). I am confident I followed the tutorial correctly, yet am experiencing different behaviour. The car is floating around unpredictably and doesn't steer properly.

I am unfortunately not familiar enough with games programming to figure out what is wrong myself, so I would appreciate any help.

Edit: I should point out that I am using the same settings the tutorial recommended for the various vehicle parameters:
Tyre Mass is 10, and Vehicle Mass is 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I was applying the wheel rotation incorrectly. Previously, according to the playing input, the wheel was rotated using the formula:

```cs
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(
    0, 
    90 + Mathf.LerpAngle(-40, 40, (_controller.Controls.x + 1)/2), 
    0
);
```

This was applying rotation in world space, I needed to multiply by the vehicles rotation to bring the wheel steer into the correct local space:

```cs
transform.rotation = _carRigidbody.transform.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(
    0, 
    90 + Mathf.LerpAngle(-40, 40, (_controller.Controls.x + 1)/2), 
    0
);
```